# What is the genitive of "service"?

Tags: saxon-genitive

Is it "a delivery service's terms and conditions" or "a delivery service' terms and conditions"?

Follow-up question: If the answer is "service'", how is it pronounced, just as "service"?

Comment: The apostrophe without an s is only for words ending in s, not words which in any way "sound like" the letter s.

Comment: Not every dictionary and style guide agrees with Lambie. Some still (the usage seems to be falling out of favor) recommend “conscience’ sake” and “justice’ sake.” For example, http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780190491482.001.0001/acref-9780190491482-e-1689 . I’ve never seen “service’ sake,” but it wouldn’t surprise me to see it as an option or recommended somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delivery service's terms and conditions

service's is pronounced "service-is"